# ClickOnce Async update not working

Tags: .net, winforms, clickonce

I've got a ClickOnce application which I need to update.
Running `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CheckfForDetailedUpdate()` returns details that there is an update available from the server and it gets the correct version number of the application on the server.

When I run the `UpdateAsync` method, nothing happens and the program hangs in the infinite while loop as shown in the code.

What could be wrong?

Here's the code

```
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
    if (ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CheckForUpdate())
    {
        long downloaded = 0;
        bool write = false;
        bool updateCompleted = false;

        deployment.UpdateCompleted += (sender, e) => updateCompleted = true;
        deployment.UpdateProgressChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            //used to write to the log file the first time anything downloads
            if (downloaded == 0)
                write = true; 

            downloaded = e.BytesCompleted;
        };

        deployment.UpdateAsync();

        //suspend while updating
        while (!updateCompleted)
        {
            //write is never true implying that nothing gets downloaded
            if (write) 
            {
                log.Info(
                    "Downloaded " + downloaded + " bytes of " + total + ".");
                write = false;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that you're blocking the main application thread in the while loop and the `UpdateCompleted` is waiting for your main application thread to become idle so that it can run. This guess is supported by MSDN documentation that states that:

> When the asynchronous update finishes or encounters an exception, ClickOnce will raise the UpdateCompleted event on the **main application thread**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think that that is the case since the while(!complete) configuration has worked before...

Comment: @VARAK - I'd say Joao is right - the same comment applies to UpdateProgressChanged - it wants to run on the main thread, that you're tying up in that tight while loop - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.updateprogresschanged.aspx

Comment: I apologize, it seems you were right. I took out the while loop and it updates. Really strange because it worked on a previous project :/ Thanks a lot!